# How to convert a variable length tuple of ints using struct.pack?

Tags: python, struct, tuples, pack

Given a tuple of varying length, in this case 4 bytes (but could be `0xFF` bytes of int):

```py
a = (0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44)
```

How can I get the tuple `a` into the format so that it can be packed as it is below (keeping in mind that `len(a)` will vary)?

```py
struct.pack('>4B', 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44)
```

Comment: `struct.pack('>%dB' % len(a), *a)`

Comment: @usr2564301 - That works great except for the case where there there is only one byte of data in a, e.g. a=(0x33) since it's not a tuple and an int can't be unpacked. So far I'm thinking of a separate command for this one case. (I didn't know about the unpack using an asterisk. TY!)